# How to display a separator after a print statement

Tags: python, string

I would like to separate my print statements with a dashed line (or something similar), but I can't find a way of doing this without printing it as a string after each output. For example:

```
a = 'Output 1'
b = 'Output 2'

separator = '\n-------------------------------------'

print(a, separator)
print(b, separator)
```

This does provide my desired output:

```
Output 1 
-------------------------------------
Output 2 
-------------------------------------
```

**Is there a better way of doing this without defining the 'separator' variable or making my own function?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I.e., you want to *automatically* add a line after *every* `print` without explicitly specifying it? No, you'll need to create your own function for that.

Comment: you can have `separator = '\n'+'-'*15` for more readable format. And there is no other way than creating your own function.

Comment: Understood, I was hoping that ```print()``` or ```IPython.display``` would take an argument that would work. Thanks for clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no - you should create your own function for that:

```
def output(x):
    sep = "\n-------------------------------------"
    print(x, separator, end="\n")
```

I think it's worth pointing out that you can make this a bit more readable using:

```
sep = f"\n{'-'*37}"
# or
sep = "\n" + "-"*37
```

You could also allow the function to take an arbitrary amount of arguments:

```
def output(*args):
    sep = f"\n{'-'*37}"
    for x in args:
        print(x, sep, end="\n")

output("Output 1", "Output 2")

"""
Output 1 
-------------------------------------
Output 2 
-------------------------------------
"""
```

Comment: Definitely more readable, I agree. Unfortunately, I was hoping to bypass all the 'variable-defining'. Thank you though.

Comment: Well, you could define the function in a separate module and then import that module to whatever module you're working in. But, as you said, unfortunately, there's no way around this.

Comment: and you can name the function as 'Print()' instead of 'output()' ;))

Comment: @SadafShafi true, but it becomes a probelm if you want to print something without the line :D unless you use the capital "P"

Comment: @gmdev in that case use 'print()' with small 'p' ;D

Comment: Seems to be the best route to take, I agree. Thanks for the answer, I'll be doing something similar.

Comment: No problem, enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
a = 'Output 1'
b = 'Output 2'

separator = '\n-------------------------------------'

print(a,b,sep =  separator, end = separator)
```

Comment: its not giving the desired output

Comment: You're asking for advice, not someone to feed you code. End parameter works just fine, no need to downvote people because you wanted something else.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a better way of doing this without defining the 'separator'
> variable or making my own function?

No. How can you print 20 `-` without defining them?

```
a = 'Output 1'
separator = '\n-------------------------------------\n'

print(a, end=separator)
```

Answer (score -2):

Print function in Python3 has an `end` parameters which allows you to specify how you would like the outputted text to finish. If your problem is to have another variable just to store the separator, something like this should work fine:

```
a = 'Output 1'
b = 'Output 2'
print(a, end = '\n-------------------------------------')
print(b, end = '\n-------------------------------------')
```

Comment: it's also not giving the desired output